# How to pass the event object to a React event handler function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

What is the correct way of passing the `event` object to a event handler function?

The event handlers:

```
// DOESN'T NEED ANY ARGUMENTS
function handleInnerDivClickWithoutArgument(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER WITHOUT ARGUMENT');
}

// NEEDS AN ARGUMENT 'msg'
function handleInnerDivClick(event,msg){
  //console.log(event);
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(msg);
}
```

**OPTION #1**

If the event handler doesn't need an extra argument, the following always works:

```
<S.Inner_DIV1
  onClick={handleInnerDivClickWithoutArgument}
>
```

**OPTION #2**

```
<S.Inner_DIV2
  onClick={ () => handleInnerDivClick(event, '>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER')}
>
```

**OPTION #3**

```
<S.Inner_DIV3
  onClick={ (event) => handleInnerDivClick(event, '>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER')}
>
```

But, from the last two, only **Option #3** is able to cancel the event propagation. **Option #2** doesn't stop the propagation, as you can see in the snippet.

**QUESTION:**

Note that **both options are able to** `console.log(event)`. Why is that? Are those events differents? What is the proper way to pass the `event` object to the handler functions and why?

**WARNING:** The `console.log(event)` line in the snippet is commented out because it takes a while to run (~10seconds). I don't know why, but it does.

```js
const styled = window.styled;

const S = {};

S.Outer_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

S.Inner_DIV1 = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

S.Inner_DIV2 = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

S.Inner_DIV3 = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
`;



function App() {


  function handleInnerDivClick(event,msg){
    //console.log(event);
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(msg);
  }
  
  function handleInnerDivClickWithoutArgument(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER WITHOUT ARGUMENT');
  }

  return (
    <S.Outer_DIV onClick={()=>console.log('OUTER DIV EVENT HANDLER WAS CALLED!')}>
      <S.Inner_DIV1
        onClick={handleInnerDivClickWithoutArgument}
      >
        S.Inner_DIV1
      </S.Inner_DIV1>
      <S.Inner_DIV2
        onClick={()=>handleInnerDivClick(event,'>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER')}
      >
        S.Inner_DIV2
      </S.Inner_DIV2>
      <S.Inner_DIV3
        onClick={(event)=>handleInnerDivClick(event,'>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER')}
      >
        S.Inner_DIV3
      </S.Inner_DIV3>
    </S.Outer_DIV>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Option 1 & option 3 both cancel for me, and option 2 has a bug so that explains why that doesn't cancel..

Comment: I'm not getting any bugs. Option 2 runs both events (inner and outer). What did you get?

Comment: Option 2 is invalid since `event` is undefined there.

Comment: @Clarity why does it log an event object, then? Try to uncomment the `console.log(event)` line and click on option #2.

Comment: I would use Option 3.

Comment: @Clarity And how does option #1 work? I'm not defining any `event` variables in that case also. Is it implicitly passed down by React?

Comment: _why does it log an event object, then?_ Because global [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is used there

Comment: @cbdev420 it's probably because `event` is undefined and when you try to stop propagation on it, it doesn't work and propagate to the outer element.

Comment: Alright, so from all comments I'm getting that if I'm using Option #1, the event is passed implicitly, otherwise I need to name it as a parameter and pass it down. Does anybody know if it needs to be the 1st parameter? And if it needs to be named as `event`?

Comment: Like pointed out option 2 the event never gets passed,.  In React you get whats called synthetic events, and it's that you need to call stopPropagation.  The event you get like pointed out is actually the current windows event, and calling stopPropgation on that will have no effect as React has already captured it and created a synthetic event.  https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: @Keith , thanks you!

Comment: @cbdev420 `onClick` expects a function with one parameter of type `MouseEvent`. Which is what `handleInnerDivClickWithoutArgument` is. Option #3 is a syntactic sugar, you are actually creating an anonymous function with one parameter and passing it, just like in Option #1, if you unsugar it it would be `<S.Inner_DIV3
  onClick={function(event){return handleInnerDivClick(event, '>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER');}}
>`. The argument name doesn't matter but it has to be the first argument as any extra argument would be ignored.

Comment: I would suggest you to follow some JavaScript tutorial to get a better grasp of it because it's an important concept in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Option #1** you are actually passing the event, since you pass the function object, it's roughly the equivalent of

```
<S.Inner_DIV1
  onClick={event => handleInnerDivClickWithoutArgument(event)}
>
```

So quite similar to **Option #3**.

In **Option #2**, you are not passing it. It's like you created a new function that doesn't have any parameter, it would be roughly the equivalent of

```
function option2() {
  return handleInnerDivClick(event, '>>> INNER DIV EVENT HANDLER');
}
<S.Inner_DIV2
  onClick={option2}
>
```

As you can see, `event` is not defined in the local scope of function `option2`, though `event` may fall back to `window.event` in the context of an event handler.

This is not React specific, it's just a misuse of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. And the `event` that option #2 logs is probably `window.event`, right?

Comment: I think so, since there is no `event` variable in the local scope of the function, it takes the one from the global scope

Comment: _event is undefined in the function option._ That's not quite true. `event` (resolved as `window.event`) is accessible in the context of an event handler, including nested calls. So `event` is _**defined**_ in `option2` as soon as it's called in the context of an event handler. However, use of `window.event` is deprecated now.

Comment: @hindmost, you're right, I will edit it. Would it be better to say that `event` is not a variable in the function scope? Or that it's undefined in the function scope?

Comment: I'd add something like "though `event` may fall back to `window.event` in the context of an event handler."